# vscode: how do I remove the thin strip next to the minimap?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm not talking about the minimap. There's a thin vertical strip next to the minimap. What is it called; how do I remove it?

See part of image marked in red.

Normally I don't have the minimap open. I opened it in this screenshot just to make the image more understandable.

[image]

Comment: Mind illustrating with an image of what you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

This horizontal line tells where the actual cursor is located relative to the whole document. For example, if the cursor (the blinking line when you type) is at the bottom of the page, then the scrollbar's horizontal line would be at the bottom of the scrollbar and vice versa.

**It can't be removed** currently, but still could be hidden by removing the document from focus (not having the typing cursor anywhere in the file).

Though, you still can hide the scrollbar completely if you want to. This would hide the horizontal line as well

#### To remove scroll bar from in-active windows

This called the `Overview Ruler` and could be easily removed by adding the following lines to `settings.json`

However, this would only remove the ruler from non active windows

```json
"editor.hideCursorInOverviewRuler": true
```

#### To remove from all windows

To remove the ruler completely, add the following to your `settings/json`

```json
"editor.scrollbar.horizontal": "hidden",
"editor.scrollbar.vertical": "hidden"
```

Then restart/reload your VScode window.

**Important**: This will give an error: `Unknown configuration setting`. Ignore it, since it would still work

Comment: I actually do have these in my config, it's not removing it though...

Comment: @Max Oh, BTW, why do you want to remove it. Is that for a specific purpose, or you just like customizing vscode to the fullest?

Comment: Update: now that I know it's the overview ruler, I got rid of it via "editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize": 0. The reason I wanted to remove it is just that it's an eye sore. I feel a tiny amount of pain everytime I look over it, and because it has colorful symbols my eyes can't just ignore it. :)

Comment: You can also change the color of it via the **color: {}** property in settings.json. These are the same selectors used by themes. You can override your current themes colors for the overview ruler with these `color:{}` settings, just remember they go inside of the `color:{}` properties curly braces. **`"editorOverviewRuler.background": "#000000"`**  --&--  **`"editorOverviewRuler.border": "#00000"`** I hide it in some of the themes I build by changing it so the bg and border are the same color as **`"editor.background": "#041435"`**